# How to Compile native library in eclipse

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

When i run native lib in eclipse android 
it display the following error:

```
    [2014-12-19 11:13:15 - NativeActivity] Unknown Application ABI: 
    [2014-12-19 11:13:15 - NativeActivity] 
    [2014-12-19 11:13:15 - NativeActivity] Unable to detect application ABI's
```

How to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You should rather add the location of your ndk directory to your path and compile it. Make sure you created Android.mk (The Make file)

If the ndk directory is in your path, issue the following command

```
cd YOUR_PROJECT DIRECTORY
```

once you are there ...

```
./ndk-build or ndk-build (or ndk-build to make a fresh build)
```

You can learn more from this link http://stevethai.wordpress.com/2010/08/04/android-helloworld-with-native-code-tutorial/ ... I'm sure your sdk and ndk versions will be different from the ones in the tutorial but you'll get the lesson.

Comment: my Android.mk is start with this LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

Comment: Here's my assumption @JOOOOOOOOOOO... You wrote some native code and having trouble to compile it, right?

Comment: pls tel me how to run?